Correct zod schema for validation
so I have a form which has the following fields: goal, escortType, customTrainingPlan, trainingPlan, and nutritionPlan.
I wnat to have the validation of the form based on the value of escortType
escortType is an enum which has three possible values.
escortType: z.enum(['Nutrition', 'Training', 'Nutrition and training'], ),

I want to have the validation of the form based on this
if the escortType is equal to Nutrition, then only the nutritionPlan is required, and neither of training plan or custom training plan are required.
if escortType is Training then either of custom training plan or training plan are required
and if escort type is Nutrition and training, then nutritionPlan is required and ALSO either of custom training plan or trainingPlan are required. difference between customTrainingPlan and trainingPlan is one is a custom one which is built on the site and sent as a string (ObjectId) and second one is upload file.
this is the schema right now, which doesn't work as expected:
const escortDetailsSchema = z
  .object({
    goal: z.enum(['Weight loss', 'Muscle gain', 'Improve fitness', 'Other']),
    escortType: z.enum(['Nutrition', 'Training', 'Nutrition and training'], ),
    nutritionPlan: fileValidation(true),
    trainingPlan: z.optional(fileValidation(true)),
    customTrainingPlan: z.optional(
      z.string().min(1, { message: hebrewTranslations['required_field'] }),
    ),
  })
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      if (data.escortType === 'Training') {
        return true; 
      }
      return !!data.nutritionPlan; 
    },
    {
      message: hebrewTranslations['required_field'],
      path: ['nutritionPlan'],
    },
  )
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      if (data.escortType === 'Nutrition') {
        return !!(data.trainingPlan || data.customTrainingPlan);
      }
      if (data.escortType === 'Nutrition and training') {
        return !!(data.trainingPlan || data.customTrainingPlan);
      }
      return true; 
    },
    {
      message: hebrewTranslations['required_field'],
      path: ['trainingPlan', 'customTrainingPlan'], 
    },
  )
  .refine(
    (data) => {
      if (
        data.escortType === 'Nutrition and training' ||
        data.escortType === 'Training'
      ) {
        const hasTrainingPlan = !!data.trainingPlan;
        const hasCustomTrainingPlan = !!data.customTrainingPlan;
        return hasTrainingPlan || hasCustomTrainingPlan || data.escortType === 'Training';
      }
      return true; 
    },
    {
      message: hebrewTranslations['required_field'],
      path: ['trainingPlan', 'customTrainingPlan'],
    },
  );

